# How to get difference of date & time and sum for date wise?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
Time1                      Time2                       isvalid
---------------------------------------------------------------
2019-11-13 21:19:13.000    2019-11-13 21:25:35.000       1
2019-11-13 21:44:11.000    2019-11-13 21:45:23.000       1
2019-11-14 09:53:51.000    2019-11-14 10:03:22.000       1
2019-11-14 12:48:01.000    2019-11-14 13:10:29.000       1
```

Now I want to get the difference between time1 & time2 and sum that and display by date.

I have tried this query :

```
SELECT COALESCE(cast(sum(DATEDIFF(MI, Time1, Time2)) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), 0) AS total
FROM mytable
WHERE Time1 >= '2019-11-13'
    AND Time1 <= '2019-11-14'
    AND isvalid = 1
```

With the above query, I am getting only difference and that is also row-wise only.

I want output like:

```
Date          total
-------------------
2019-11-13      7 
2019-11-14      32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query using `DATEDIFF()` function.

```
create table sampledata(dtStart DateTime, 
   dtEnd DateTime,
   isValid bit)

insert into sampledata values
('2019-11-13 21:19:13.000', '2019-11-13 21:25:35.000', 1),
('2019-11-13 21:44:11.000', '2019-11-13 21:45:23.000', 1),
('2019-11-14 09:53:51.000', '2019-11-14 10:03:22.000', 1),
('2019-11-14 12:48:01.000', '2019-11-14 13:10:29.000', 1)

select * from sampledata

select dtStart, sum(TotMin) as TotMin from(
select cast(dtStart as Date) as dtStart, DATEDIFF(minute, dtStart, dtend) as TotMin
from sampledata
)a group by dtStart
```

Here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22b98f570564953d3376ace794f3b40b) demo.